# How can I append a total to a table and split the table by group (order_id)?

Tags: mysql

I am currently using:

```
select order_id as 'Order ID',
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y') as 'Date',
    prod_title as 'Item',
    amount as 'Amount'
from transactions
where date >= '2016-10-01'
order by order_id,
    amount desc;
```

This first orders by `order_id` then by `amount` in descending order, which allows me to group orders regardless of date.

I'm wondering how I can split each grouping of order_id so I get something like this:

```
|3265|01|
|3265|02|
---------
|2613|03|
---------
.
.
.
|    |06|<-total
```

Is that clear? Also, how do I append a total?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I may or may not work, depending on whether you have multiple rows for a given `order_id`:

```
select order_id as 'Order ID',
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y') as 'Date',
    prod_title as 'Item',
    SUM(amount) as 'Amount'       -- changed
from transactions
where date >= '2016-10-01'
GROUP BY order_id  WITH ROLLUP    -- added
order by order_id,
    amount desc;
```

If that fails, then

```
( SELECT ... as you have, but without ORDER BY ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT NULL, NULL, 'Total', SUM(amount)
       from transactions 
       where date >= '2016-10-01' )
ORDER BY order_id,
    amount desc;
```

This will put the Total at the top; that can be fixed by changing to something like

```
ORDER BY order_id IS NOT NULL, order_id, amount DESC
```